# One SharePoint to search in another SharePoint

Tags: search

I have one SharePoint site runs on a server and another one which is wiki type SharePoint.

For example, one share point url is:
\work\sharepoint1
and the second one is:
\work\sharepoint2

Now, when I run a search in my first SharePoint site it is only searching locally. I want it to search in the other sharepoint2 aswell.

I hope someone can help me out here. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Crawling another SharePoint as content source is possible in all versions, as outlined here:
[Use content sources effectively](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn535606.aspx#BKMK_UseContentSources)

> When you create a Search service application, the search system automatically creates and configures one content source, which is named Local SharePoint sites. This preconfigured content source is for crawling user profiles, and for crawling all SharePoint sites in the web applications with which the Search service application is associated. You can also use this content source for crawling content in other SharePoint farms, including SharePoint Server 2007 farms, SharePoint Server 2010 farms, or other SharePoint Server 2013 farms.

Anyway, you need to take some extra checks, and actions, in order to ensure the two farms can communicate properly, and the crawler has rights to perform his job on the farm that needs to be indexed.

For SP2013:
[Configure trust for search between two SharePoint Server 2013 farms](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133749.aspx)